# IP address and port of log requests in Kibana

Tags: logstash, kibana

Please can someone tell me if it is possible to add the IP address and port available fields in my Kibana to see which logs belong to my application instance. Where do i configure in order to enable this feature.

For example: I am sending log requests like this and I have 4 applications with multiple instances of them

```
2020-01-14 00:21:12.869  INFO [microservice1,48f1befc87d3f220,48f1befc87d3f220,false] 8278 --- [nio-8001-exec-7] c.s.m.c.Microservice1Controller          : This is an INFO log
2020-01-14 00:21:12.869 ERROR [microservice1,48f1befc87d3f220,48f1befc87d3f220,false] 8278 --- [nio-8001-exec-7] c.s.m.c.Microservice1Controller          : This is an ERROR log
```

Picture of my kibana UI with the available fields:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kibana can only display fields that were indexed into Elasticsearch. Kibana is just a visual platform that lets you search your data in a graphical manner instead of using the REST-Api.

So if your documents don't contain any source.ip or source.port fields, how should Kibana display them?

> Q: Where do i configure in order to enable this feature
>
> A: There is no general setting that tracks the IP's and Ports

You would need to add these fields into your created logs, e.g.:

```
2020-01-14 00:21:12.869  INFO [microservice1,48f1befc87d3f220,48f1befc87d3f220,false] 192.168.19.100:4712 8278 --- [nio-8001-exec-7] c.s.m.c.Microservice1Controller          : This is an INFO log
2020-01-14 00:21:12.869 ERROR [microservice1,48f1befc87d3f220,48f1befc87d3f220,false] 192.168.19.101:4812 8278 --- [nio-8001-exec-7] c.s.m.c.Microservice1Controller          : This is an ERROR log
```

With that, you can extract the IP's and Ports and **index them as separate fields of your documents into elasticsearch.**